# cant connect google instance via RDP

Tags: windows, instance, google-compute-engine, rdp

I can't connect my instance after I tried to change "Use the following IP address" in IPv4 settings (Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center -> Ethernet - Properties -> IPv4 Settings) to a specified IP. I've tried to restart from console.cloud.google.com, but still not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to  stop your virtual machine instance, then you can restart the instance with its original configuration, using the [instances().start](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start) method. This method boots up a powered-down virtual machine instance that is currently in a TERMINATED state.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Google Compute Engine docs on RDP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/connecting-to-windows-instance#rdp):

> If you run into issues logging in to your instance using RDP, you might not have a firewall rule that allows RDP traffic on port 3389 (`tcp:3389`). For instructions on how to add a firewall rule, see [Adding a firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall).